# EMR Yarn application submission via REST

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have an Hadoop cluster in AWS with YARN, to which I submit spark applications. I work via REST requests, submitting  XML as specified in this documentation: [YARN REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_APISubmit_Application). It works great for the regular cluster.

I'm currently doing a POC for working with EMR cluster instead of the usual one, where I use the existing REST commands and simply communicate with the internal YARN of the EMR via SSH, as specified here: [Web access of internal EMR services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html). It works great for most of the REST commands, such as `POST http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application`, but when I submit a new application it fails immediately and reports that it cannot find the ApplicationMaster.

> Log Type: stderr
>
> Log Upload Time: Sun Feb 03 17:18:35 +0000 2019
>
> Log Length: 88
>
> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster
> ```

I suspected this is connected to the classpath somehow, and when I added to the REST submit application  node the classpath flag with the EMR FS location of all the jars (/usr/lib/spark/jars/*), it finds the ApplicationMaster but then fails to find Jars in the core instances, with this strange error log:

> Log Type: stderr
>
> Log Upload Time: Thu Jan 31 15:11:21 +0000 2019
>
> Log Length: 89
>
> ```
> Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.spark.jars.datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
> ```

The most unusual thing is the way it tries to describe the jar it cannot find, rather than the class. After further investigation, I found the reason: when the Java command is sent to the Core instance, it resolves the classpath to its three files: `java -server -classpath /usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar ...` and therefore tries to execute "/usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" as if it was a runnable. The problem is that if I try to change the classpath to be more specific, or if I try to remove it, the application fails again for not finding the ApplicationMaster.

The REST request I send to YARN is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<application-submission-context> 
<application-id>application_1549270910165_0001</application-id> 
<application-name> .... some name .....</application-name> 
<queue>default</queue> 
<priority>0</priority> 
<am-container-spec> 
<local-resources> 
    <entry>

 ....... MANY MANY RESOURCES ......

        </value>
    </entry>

</local-resources> 
<environment> 
<entry> 
<key>SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR</key> 
<value>..... staging directory in our HDFS ..... </value> 
</entry> 
<entry> 
<key>CLASSPATH</key> 
<value>$PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:/usr/lib/spark/jars/*:/usr/lib/spark/yarn/lib/*:%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%:%HAOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*:%HADOOP_COMMON_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:%HADOOP_HDFS_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*:%HADOOP_YARN_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:%HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__</value> 
</entry>
<entry>
<key>SPARK_USER</key>
<value>... user name ....</value>
</entry>
</environment>
<commands> 
<command>command=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath '/usr/lib/spark/jars/*' -server -Xmx5120M -Djava.io.tmpdir=$PWD/tmp '-XX:hashCode=0' '-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-client.cfg' '-Dhdp.version=2.8.4' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=&lt;LOG_DIR&gt; org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster ... some jar and arguments ....  --properties-file $PWD/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1&gt; &lt;LOG_DIR&gt;/stdout 2&gt; &lt;LOG_DIR&gt;/stderr</command> 
</commands> 
</am-container-spec> 
<unmanaged-AM>false</unmanaged-AM> 
<max-app-attempts>1</max-app-attempts> 
<resource> 
<memory>5632</memory> 
<vCores>1</vCores> 
</resource> 
<application-type>SPARK</application-type> 
<keep-containers-across-application-attempts>false</keep-containers-across-application-attempts> 
<application-tags> 
<tag>.... product tag .....</tag> 
</application-tags> 
<log-aggregation-context/> 
<attempt-failures-validity-interval>1</attempt-failures-validity-interval> 
<reservation-id/> 
</application-submission-context>
```

I'd appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I found that the reason the application could not load the class `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster` is because this isn't the version of `ApplicationMaster` the EMR core instance uses - it uses `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.applications.distributedshell.ApplicationMaster`, which requires the `CLASSPATH` segment in the input to include `/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*`. I changed the two parameters in the input XML of the REST request and it succeeded to launch. I'll still need to configure the correct `CLASSPATH` for the EMR implementation to get the application to complete successfully, but the main challenge of this question is solved.

**Update**: eventually I decided that adding a step to the EMR and using the arguments there is actually a much easier way to handle it. I added to the maven dependencies the EMR AWS Java SDK:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-emr</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.486</version>
</dependency>
```

and added this code:

```
AddJobFlowStepsResult result = emr.addJobFlowSteps(new AddJobFlowStepsRequest()
            .withJobFlowId(clusterId)
            .withSteps(new StepConfig()
                    .withName(name)
                    .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CONTINUE)
                    .withHadoopJarStep(new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                            .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                            .withArgs(stepargs))));
```

The stepargs are taken from my original REST request, including the jars and the files to use - simply using spark-submit:

```
List<String> stepargs = new ArrayList<String>();
stepargs.add("spark-submit");
stepargs.add("--class");
stepargs.add(mainClass);
stepargs.add("--deploy-mode");
stepargs.add("cluster");
stepargs.add("--master");
stepargs.add("yarn");
stepargs.add("--files");
stepargs.add(files);
stepargs.add("--jars");
stepargs.add(jars);
stepargs.add("--properties-file");
stepargs.add(confFileName);
stepargs.add(jar);
Iterator<String> itr = args.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String arg = itr.next();
    if (arg.equals("--arg")) {
        stepargs.add(itr.next());
    }
}
```